# Why IdentityMapper disappears in the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce library?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

In the older version of hadoop library (i.e., org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib), there is a basic implementation of Mapper called [IdentityMapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityMapper.html), which essentially passes all the key-value pairs to a Reducer.

However, I found in the newer version of hadoop library (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib), it
does not have any class called IdentityMapper (all the subclasses of Mapper can be found
[here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html)).

Can I know whether the IdentityMapper change its name or disappear in the new library?

If the answer is the second one, can I further know why IdentityMapper disappears? Does this mean
we can chain multiple Reducers without having a Mapper in between?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suddenly realize the design ...

The short answer is: the new Mapper is the old IdentityMapper.

Here is a longer answer:

In the old library, [Mapper](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html) is an interface, and its basic implementation is called [IdentityMapper](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityMapper.html).

However, in the new library, it no longer has a base interface for mappers.  Instead, it has a common base class for mappers called [Mapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html), whose implementation is the previous IdentityMapper.